# Jquery before() method in each() loop

Tags: jquery

I am trying to use before() method in each() loop on each of the input fields. I need to assign labels to inputs.
It doesn't work.
However when I use prepend method it inserts the labels inside the inputs.

### The before() code:

```
var zuzu = jQuery("form#caspioform :input"); 
jQuery(zuzu).each(function(){ 
    var label = jQuery("label[for='"+jQuery(this).attr('id')+"']"); // 
    jQuery(this).before(label.parent().html()); 
})
```

---

### The prepend() code:

```
var zuzu = jQuery("form#caspioform :input"); 
jQuery(zuzu).each(function(){ 
    var label = jQuery("label[for='"+jQuery(this).attr('id')+"']"); // 
    jQuery(this).prepend(label.parent().html()); 
})
```

---

THE FULL CODE which removes the table and adds extracted input fields into the form:

```
var zuzu = jQuery("form#caspioform :input");
jQuery(zuzu).each(function() {
  var label = jQuery("label[for='" + jQuery(this).attr('id') + "']"); // 
  jQuery(this).before(label.parent().html());
})
jQuery("#caspioform table").remove();
jQuery("#caspioform").append(zuzu);
```

---

### The HTML CODE OF THE ORIGINAL FORM:

```
<form style="margin: 0px;" action="http://b5.caspio.com/dp.asp" id="caspioform" method="post">
  <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <table cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse: collapse;" id="cbTable_7aea6b2e1aa15b" name="cbTable">
            <tbody>
              <tr onmouseout="cbRowHover(this,'transparent');" onmouseover="cbRowHover(this,'none');" style="padding: 7px; background-color: transparent;">
                <td style="text-align: left; vertical-align: top; padding: 7px;" colspan="2">
                  <h1>CONTACT OUR FIRM</h1>
                  <p>NOTE: Fields with a <span style="color:#ff0000">*</span> indicate a required field.</p>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td style="text-align: right; vertical-align: middle; width: 90px; padding: 3px 5px; white-space: normal; color: #000000;font-size: 12px;font-family: Arial ;">
                  <label for="InsertRecordName">Name:<span style="color: #FF0000;font-size: 12px;font-family: Arial ;margin-left: 2px;">*</span>
                  </label>
                </td>
                <td style="text-align: left; vertical-align: top; padding: 3px 7px; white-space: nowrap;">
                  <input type="text" value="" id="InsertRecordName" name="InsertRecordName" maxlength="255" size="50" style="color: #666666; font-size: 12px; font-family: Arial ; font-style: normal; font-weight: normal; border: 1px solid #d1d0d1; padding: 5px; margin: 4px 0;">
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr onmouseout="cbRowHover(this,'transparent');" onmouseover="cbRowHover(this,'none');" style="padding: 7px; background-color: transparent;">
                <td style="text-align: right; vertical-align: middle; width: 90px; padding: 3px 5px; white-space: normal; color: #000000;font-size: 12px;font-family: Arial ;">
                  <label for="InsertRecordEmail">Email:<span style="color: #FF0000;font-size: 12px;font-family: Arial ;margin-left: 2px;">*</span>
                  </label>
                </td>
                <td style="text-align: left; vertical-align: top; padding: 3px 7px; white-space: nowrap;">
                  <input type="text" value="" id="InsertRecordEmail" name="InsertRecordEmail" maxlength="255" size="50" style="color: #666666; font-size: 12px; font-family: Arial ; font-style: normal; font-weight: normal; border: 1px solid #d1d0d1; padding: 5px; margin: 4px 0;">
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td style="text-align: right; vertical-align: middle; width: 90px; padding: 3px 5px; white-space: normal; color: #000000;font-size: 12px;font-family: Arial ;text-align: right;">
                  <label for="InsertRecordState">State:</label>
                </td>
                <td style="text-align: left; vertical-align: top; padding: 3px 7px; white-space: nowrap;">
                  <select style="color: #666666;font-size: 12px;font-family: Arial ;font-style: normal;font-weight: normal;border: 1px solid #d1d0d1;padding: 10px;margin: 4px 0;" name="InsertRecordState" id="InsertRecordState">
                    <option value="Alabama">Alabama</option>
                    <option value="Alaska">Alaska</option>
                    <option value="Arizona">Arizona</option>
                    <option value="Arkansas">Arkansas</option>
                    <option value="California">California</option>
                    <option value="Colorado">Colorado</option>
                    <option value="Connecticut">Connecticut</option>
                    <option value="Delaware">Delaware</option>
                    <option value="District of Columbia">District of Columbia</option>
                    <option value="Florida">Florida</option>
                    <option value="Georgia">Georgia</option>
                    <option value="Guam">Guam</option>
                    <option value="Hawaii">Hawaii</option>
                    <option value="Idaho">Idaho</option>
                    <option selected="selected" value="Illinois">Illinois</option>
                    <option value="Indiana">Indiana</option>
                    <option value="Iowa">Iowa</option>
                    <option value="Kansas">Kansas</option>
                    <option value="Kentucky">Kentucky</option>
                    <option value="Louisiana">Louisiana</option>
                    <option value="Maine">Maine</option>
                    <option value="Maryland">Maryland</option>
                    <option value="Massachusetts">Massachusetts</option>
                    <option value="Michigan">Michigan</option>
                    <option value="Minnesota">Minnesota</option>
                    <option value="Mississippi">Mississippi</option>
                    <option value="Missouri">Missouri</option>
                    <option value="Montana">Montana</option>
                    <option value="Nebraska">Nebraska</option>
                    <option value="Nevada">Nevada</option>
                    <option value="New Hampshire">New Hampshire</option>
                    <option value="New Jersey">New Jersey</option>
                    <option value="New Mexico">New Mexico</option>
                    <option value="New York">New York</option>
                    <option value="North Carolina">North Carolina</option>
                    <option value="North Dakota">North Dakota</option>
                    <option value="Ohio">Ohio</option>
                    <option value="Oklahoma">Oklahoma</option>
                    <option value="Oregon">Oregon</option>
                    <option value="Pennsylvania">Pennsylvania</option>
                    <option value="Puerto Rico">Puerto Rico</option>
                    <option value="Rhode Island">Rhode Island</option>
                    <option value="South Carolina">South Carolina</option>
                    <option value="South Dakota">South Dakota</option>
                    <option value="Tennessee">Tennessee</option>
                    <option value="Texas">Texas</option>
                    <option value="Utah">Utah</option>
                    <option value="Vermont">Vermont</option>
                    <option value="Virginia">Virginia</option>
                    <option value="Washington">Washington</option>
                    <option value="West Virginia">West Virginia</option>
                    <option value="Wisconsin">Wisconsin</option>
                    <option value="Wyoming">Wyoming</option>
                  </select>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr onmouseout="cbRowHover(this,'transparent');" onmouseover="cbRowHover(this,'none');" style="padding: 7px; background-color: transparent;">
                <td style="text-align: right; vertical-align: middle; width: 90px; padding: 3px 5px; white-space: normal; color: #000000;font-size: 12px;font-family: Arial ;text-align: right;">
                  <label for="InsertRecordZIP">ZIP:</label>
                </td>
                <td style="text-align: left; vertical-align: top; padding: 3px 7px; white-space: nowrap;">
                  <input type="text" value="" id="InsertRecordZIP" name="InsertRecordZIP" maxlength="10" size="10" style="color: #666666; font-size: 12px; font-family: Arial ; font-style: normal; font-weight: normal; border: 1px solid #d1d0d1; padding: 5px; margin: 4px 0;">
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td style="text-align: right; vertical-align: middle; width: 90px; padding: 3px 5px; white-space: normal; color: #000000;font-size: 12px;font-family: Arial ;">
                  <label for="InsertRecordPhone">Phone:<span style="color: #FF0000;font-size: 12px;font-family: Arial ;margin-left: 2px;">*</span>
                  </label>
                </td>
                <td style="text-align: left; vertical-align: top; padding: 3px 7px; white-space: nowrap;">
                  <input type="text" value="" id="InsertRecordPhone" name="InsertRecordPhone" maxlength="14" size="20" style="color: #666666; font-size: 12px; font-family: Arial ; font-style: normal; font-weight: normal; border: 1px solid #d1d0d1; padding: 5px; margin: 4px 0;">
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr onmouseout="cbRowHover(this,'transparent');" onmouseover="cbRowHover(this,'none');" style="padding: 7px; background-color: transparent;">
                <td style="text-align: left; vertical-align: top; padding: 7px;" colspan="2">
                  <h2>How would you prefer to be contacted?</h2>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td style="text-align: right; vertical-align: middle; width: 90px; padding: 3px 5px; white-space: normal; color: #000000;font-size: 12px;font-family: Arial ;text-align: right;">
                  <label for="InsertRecordContact_Method">&nbsp;</label>
                </td>
                <td style="text-align: left; vertical-align: top; padding: 3px 7px; white-space: nowrap;">
                  <span "=" " style="color: #000000; font-size: 12px; font-family: Arial ; font-style: normal; font-weight: normal; "><input type="radio " value="E-Mail " id="InsertRecordContact_Method0 " name="InsertRecordContact_Method "><label for="InsertRecordContact_Method0
                  ">E-Mail</label><br><input type="radio " value="Phone " id="InsertRecordContact_Method1 " name="InsertRecordContact_Method "><label for="InsertRecordContact_Method1 ">Phone</label><br><input type="radio " value="No Preference " id="InsertRecordContact_Method2
                  " name="InsertRecordContact_Method "><label for="InsertRecordContact_Method2 ">No Preference</label><br></span></td></tr><tr onmouseout="cbRowHover(this, 'transparent'); " onmouseover="cbRowHover(this, 'none'); " style="padding: 7px; background-color:
                  transparent; "><td style="text-align: left; vertical-align: top; padding: 7px; " colspan="2 "><h2>Briefly describe your legal issue.</h2></td></tr><tr><td style="text-align: right; vertical-align: middle; width: 90px; padding: 3px 5px;
                  white-space: normal; color: #000000;font-size: 12px;font-family: Arial ;text-align: right; "><label for="InsertRecordMessage ">&nbsp;</label></td><td style="text-align: left; vertical-align: top; padding: 3px 7px; white-space: nowrap;
                  "><textarea id="InsertRecordMessage " name="InsertRecordMessage " onkeypress="return cbTextAreaHelper.controlKeyPress(event, this, 750); " onkeydown="return cbTextAreaHelper.controlKeyDown(event, this, 750); " oninput="cbTextAreaHelper.displayTip(this,
                  750, null, null, null, 0); " onchange="cbTextAreaHelper.displayTip(this, 750, null, null, null, 0); " onkeyup="cbTextAreaHelper.displayTip(this, 750, null, null, null, 0); " rows="5 " cols="50 " style="color: #666666; font-size: 12px;
                  font-family: Arial ; font-style: normal; font-weight: normal; border: 1px solid #d1d0d1; padding: 5px; margin:4px 0; "></textarea></td></tr><tr onmouseout="cbRowHover(this, 'transparent'); " onmouseover="cbRowHover(this, 'none');
                  " style="padding: 7px; background-color: transparent; "><td style="text-align: left; vertical-align: top; padding: 7px; " colspan="2 "><p><img align="left " style="padding-right: 10px; padding-bottom: 5px; " src="/images/formDisclaimer.gif
                  ">The use of the Internet or this form for communication with the firm or any individual member of the firm does not establish an attorney-client relationship. Confidential or time-sensitive information should not be sent through this form.</p></td></tr><tr><td style="text-align: right; vertical-align: middle; width: 90px; padding: 3px 5px; white-space: normal; color: #000000;font-size: 12px;font-family: Arial ; "><label for="InsertRecordDisclaimer ">&nbsp;<span style="color: #FF0000;font-size: 12px;font-family:
                  Arial ;margin-left: 2px; ">*</span></label></td><td style="text-align: left; vertical-align: top; padding: 3px 7px; white-space: nowrap; "><span style="color: #000000; font-size: 12px; font-family: Arial ; font-style: normal; font-weight:
                  normal; "><input type="checkbox " value="YES " id="InsertRecordDisclaimer " name="InsertRecordDisclaimer "> <label for="InsertRecordDisclaimer ">I have read and understand the <a href="/disclaimer
                  ">disclaimer</a>.</label></span></td></tr><tr onmouseout="cbRowHover(this, 'transparent'); " onmouseover="cbRowHover(this, 'none'); " style="padding: 7px; background-color: transparent; "><td style="text-align: right; vertical-align: middle; width: 90px; padding: 3px 5px; white-space: normal;
                  color: #000000;font-size: 12px;font-family: Arial ;text-align: right; "><label for="cbParamCaptcha1@Image ">&nbsp;</label></td><td style="text-align: left; vertical-align: top; padding: 3px 7px; white-space: nowrap; "><img width="168
                  " height="59 " title="Click to reload new image " alt="Security code. Click to reload new image " src="http://b5.caspio.com/captchaSource/image.aspx?ctoken=7C50F65B2BEF13AA3AE42D86A808E017A8AD23C54BE8BAD83E346106F162A6E2877D4B7E511E922AC414FC2CC5D73E9C200D3589BE52FAA98E8439E84ECD71E1&amp;t=34050
                  " onclick="try{var v_c=t his; v_c.src=v _c.src.replace(/[&amp;][t][=][0-9]+$/gi, '') + '&amp;t=' + String(new Date().getTime());}catch(e){} " id="captcha "><input type="hidden " value="7C50F65B2BEF13AA3AE42D86A808E017A8AD23C54BE8BAD83E346106F162A6E2877D4B7E511E922AC414FC2CC5D73E9C200D3589BE52FAA98E8439E84ECD71E1
                  " name="captchasession "></td></tr><tr><td style="text-align: right; vertical-align: middle; width: 90px; padding: 3px 5px; white-space: normal; color: #000000;font-size: 12px;font-family: Arial ; "><label for="cbParamCaptcha1
                  ">Enter the code you see above.<span style="color: #FF0000;font-size: 12px;font-family: Arial ;margin-left: 2px; ">*</span></label></td><td style="text-align: left; vertical-align: top; padding: 3px 7px; white-space: nowrap; "><input type="text " value=" " id="cbParamCaptcha1
                  " name="cbParamCaptcha1 " maxlength="255 " size="25 " style="color: #666666; font-size: 12px; font-family: Arial ; font-style: normal; font-weight: normal; border: 1px solid #d1d0d1; padding: 5px; margin: 4px 0; "><a href="# " onclick="f_ShowPlayer_7aea6b2e1aa15b();try{this.blur();}catch(v_e){}
                  return false; "><img border="0 " alt="Audio Captcha. Listen and type what you hear " title="Listen and type what you hear " src="http://b5.caspio.com/images/ac_handicap_icon_small.gif "></a><span id="AC_container_7aea6b2e1aa15b
                  "></span></td></tr><tr onmouseout="cbRowHover(this, 'transparent'); " onmouseover="cbRowHover(this, 'none'); " style="padding: 7px; "><td style="text-align: left; vertical-align: top; padding: 7px; " colspan="2 "><script language="JavaScript ">
function f_a(v_id)
{
return document.getElementById(v_id);
}
f_a('InsertRecordPhone').maxLength = 14;
f_a('InsertRecordPhone').onkeyup = function(v_e)
{
v_e = v_e || window.event;
if (v_e.keyCode &gt;= 65 &amp;&amp; v_e.keyCode &lt;= 90){
this.value = this.value.substr(0, this.value.length - 1);
return false;
}else if (v_e.keyCode &gt;= 37 &amp;&amp; v_e.keyCode &lt;= 40){
return true;
}
var v_value =(this.value.replace(/[^\d]/g, ''));
if (v_value.length==7) {
this.value = (v_value.substring(0,3) + "- " + v_value.substring(3,7));}
else if(v_value.length==10){
this.value = ("( " + v_value.substring(0,3) + ") " + v_value.substring(3,6) + "- " + v_value.substring(6,10));
};
}
</script></td></tr><tr><td style="padding: 10px 7px; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; " colspan="2 "><input type="submit " onmouseout="cbButtonHover(this,
                  'color: #000000; font-size: 12px; font-family: Arial ; font-style: normal; font-weight: bold; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; width: auto; height: auto; margin: 0px 3px; padding: 8px 18px; background-color: #e1ddd1; border: 0;'); " onmouseover="cbButtonHover(this,
                  'color: #000000; font-size: 12px; font-family: Arial ; font-style: normal; font-weight: bold; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; background-color: #b3b0a6; width: auto; height: auto; margin: 0px 3px; padding: 8px 18px; border:0px;'); " style="color: #000000; font-size: 12px; font-family: Arial ; font-style: normal; font-weight: bold; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; width: auto; height: auto; margin: 0px 3px; padding: 8px 18px; background-color: #e1ddd1;
                  border: 0; " value="Submit " id="Submit " name="Submit "></td></tr></tbody></table></td></tr></tbody></table><input type="hidden " value="cd283000f0a1d3c218d34909a075 " name="AppKey "><input type="hidden " value="_7aea6b2e1aa15b
                  " id="cbUniqueFormId_7aea6b2e1aa15b " name="cbUniqueFormId "><input type="hidden " value="3 " name="PrevPageID "><input type="hidden " value="http://www.cosleycriminaldefense.com/contact " name="pathname "><input type="hidden " value="1
                  " name="Mod0InsertRecord "><input type="hidden " value="3 " name="Mod0InsertRecordPageID "><input type="hidden " value="Caspio " name="cbAP "><input type="hidden " value="SYSDATE " name="InsertRecordSubmission_Date " id="InsertRecordSubmission_Date
                  "><input type="hidden " value="Contact Page " name="InsertRecordForm " id="InsertRecordForm "><input type="hidden " value="www.cosleycriminaldefense.com " name="InsertRecordWebsite " id="InsertRecordWebsite "></form>
```

Comment: so... what is the problem?

Comment: I need to add a label which has an id of the input next to the input. The code above doesn't work with before() method.

Comment: I would also be beneficial to see some HTML or even better, a jsfiddle example of the issue.

Comment: In the question I posted an original FORM code from which I am trying to extract all inputs from the table and assign those inputs their corresponding labels.

Comment: You already have labels for inputs so what is purpose?

Comment: The purpose is to extract all of the inputs and labels from the table and recreate form using DIVs

Answer (score 0):

Prepend the label to the input's parent. Just change this line:

```
jQuery(this).prepend(label.parent().html());
```

to:

```
jQuery(this).parent().prepend(label.parent().html());
```

Note the `parent()` function just before `jQuery(this)`. Your code should work now.

Comment: By the way after I do all of this I remove the table and create a new form where I have all the inputs. So I tried to wrap jQuery(this) like this:        jQuery(this).wrap("<div></div>"); And then prepend to a parent but I have all the DIVs above all inputs.
      jQuery(this).parent().prepend(label.parent().html());

Comment: But how do I create a parent for jQuery(this)? Currently all of the inputs share the same parent: <form>

Comment: `jQuery( this ).wrap( '<div>' )` like I did in the js fiddle.

Comment: I get all the divs above all the inputs:                                                     `code` <form id="caspioform" style="margin: 0px;" action="http://b5.caspio.com/dp.asp" method="post">
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<input id="InsertRecordName" type="text" value="" name="InsertRecordName" maxlength="255" size="50" style="color: #666666;font-size: 12px;font-family: Arial ;font-style: normal;font-weight: normal;border: 1px solid #d1d0d1;padding: 5px;margin: 4px 0;"> `code`
... and so on....

Comment: Oh! The problem is the `var zuzu = jQuery("form#caspioform :input");` selector. This code is not retrieving the inputs. Try `var zuzu = jQuery("form#caspioform").find(  'input' );`

Comment: Or just `var zuzu = jQuery( 'form#caspioform input' );` without the `:`.

Comment: No, it does retrieve all the inputs with `code` var zuzu = jQuery("form#caspioform :input"); `code` Right now the problem is that I cannot create a parent for each input. All of the parent DIVs show up above all of the inputs. Div doesn't seem to wrap around each input.

Comment: I did exactly like you suggested above but the inputs still don't get wrapped in divs. DIVs appear empty and go one by one right after <form>

Comment: Remove this line of code `jQuery("#caspioform").append(zuzu);`. I think it is removing the inputs from the recent created divs and putting all of then back to #caspioform element root.